# How can I create a calculated table / Power Query table in Power BI that I can summarise data across different tables for price elasticity analysis?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to look at price elasticity analysis.

I have an order table with Date, Order ID
A calendar table with date
An order items table with Order ID, Product ID, Quantity, Unit Price

I would like to create a new table that contains

Date, ProductID, sum(quantity), avg(unit price), sum(quantity) for previous day, avg(unit price) for previous day.. then I can calculate price elasticity of demand.. how can I do this in either a calculated table in Power BI or via Power Query?

I tried a calculated table with the summarise function but it would only let me pass one table, I couldnt take a field from the calendar table and then from the order items table

Comment: Update your question with sample tables in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). In the meantime, see if [`SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sure, but how can I look at summarise columns across multiple tables, I believe only 1 table can be passed in? I need my data to be organised by date, but the date field comes from the calendar table (via orderitems.orderid = orders.id, then orders.date = calendar.date.

Then wanting date, productid, sum quantity etc. etc

Comment: `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` supports multiple table/columns.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could share a basic example! 

Again, calendar table has date.
Order table has orderid and date. 
Order item table has orderid, productid, quantity, unitprice. 


Could you please provide an example using SUMMARIZECOLUMNS 
that generates a table with: 

date, product id, sum quantity, avg unitprice. 

Thank you thank you! I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
MyNewTable =
  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Calendar'[Date],
    'Order Items'[Product Id],
    "Sum Qty", SUM('Order Items'[Quantity]),
    "Avg Unit Price", AVERAGE('Order Items'[Unit Price])
  )
```